# Difference between pure object oriented and object oriented language

Tags: java, c++, .net, c, oop

What is difference between these two.I google it down but could not find the satisfied answer.For example java is a oop(Object oriented programming) but not pure oop(was written on some sites).Can anybody explain?

Comment: Java enforces OOP (I.e. everything is in classes) whereas C++ is not specifically a OOP language, i.e. you can do things in C++ that does not require any kind of OOP but it's supported. Is this what you mean?

Comment: In a pure OO language, everything is an object, and every action is taken through them (Smalltalk, for instance). In a language like Java, there are other data types, primitives, and it is possible to have static members, which are called (or should be, at least) on a class, not on an object.

Comment: @ Phorce:-In java everything is not in classes.F.e int float(I know there are wrapper classes).Secondly data base in java is on in oops(Unless u choose hibernate).

Comment: Watch this [video](https://vimeo.com/43659004) you'll really find a different explanation of what OO really means.

Comment: @iasias: yes, everything is in classes, but "in a class" does not mean "in an object". also, that's not what he meant. he didn't say a float IS a class, he said floats are used in classes (but I agree with you, his point was vague and incomplete at best)

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: the question is not "what is OO", the question is, "what is the difference between PURE OO and OO"

Comment: Any sort of expressed fundamental view (like "pure OOP") is indistinguishable from a parody of it.

Comment: There is no pure OOP languages in general use AFAIK.

Comment: Note that in the case of current  OOP languages, the methods for those objects are still procedural. I'm not sure what would be meant by a "pure OOP" language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java is oop but not pure because, There are Primitive data type in java like int, float etc. and they are not classes/Objects. This is only one reason that java is not Pure OOP.
For example of Pure OOP . Objective C is Pure OOP language in which every thing is in the form of object.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, in a pure OO language *everything* accessable in the language is an object (where even the classes that define objects can be object instances of meta-classes which in turn can be object instances of themselves).  In Java and C++ there are basic language elements that aren't objects: most notably the primitive data types (or built-in types) such as `int`, `float`, `char` *etc*.

Comment: Better to say they're not class types - in C++, an *object* is any region of memory with a type, which includes `int`s, `float`s, `char`s, etc.

Comment: @JosephMansfield OK, but the C++ standard's use of the word "object" is *very* different to the classical OO use of the word.

Comment: Sure, so describing it in terms of "classes", which basically has the same meaning across both example languages, is probably clearer. Or just clarify that you mean the OOP meaning of "object".

Answer (score 1):

In a purely object-oriented language, everything is an object. However, in object-oriented languages, you may have non-object variables (e.g. static variables).

Comment: Why would a static variable be of non-object type?